# Overfitting the (non-nested) cross validation set

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, cross-validation

This is a follow up query to [this query](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/438651/overfitting-the-validation-set/551945#551945)

***In one line***: I wish to understand why is it that we will severely over fit the cross validation set (and hence need nested cross validation to correctly account for the optimism in non-nested cross validation procedure) if we keep on increasing model complexity.

Here is a paper which talks about non-nested (flat) cross validation and nested cross-validation:

Jacques Wainer, Gavin Cawley, "Nested cross-validation when selecting classifiers is overzealous for most practical applications", Expert Systems with Applications, Volume 182, 2021. [(www)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.eswa.2021.115222)

Background:

1. Reason for training optimism: This one is ***easy***. If we train on a set by making the model more and more complicated we will perfectly learn the noise in the dataset and the learning curve will monotonically decrease to 0.
2. Reason for validation set optimism: This one is harder to comprehend and is explained in the query I pointed to at the beginning of this query. Basically, the validation set may have the ***same*** kind of noise as is learned by one of the candidate models. This may lead to over or under fitting the original data set.
3. Reason for cross validation set optimism: This is my ***main*** query. We do k fold cross validation. We split the data into k folds - we train on k-1 folds and test on the k-th fold. This has a ***signature*** like Training optimism (please see simulation below). What do I mean by that? The learning curve of the training error on the trained cross validation folds (k in number) is monotonically decreasing to zero just like in Case 1. Can someone please show me how to convince myself that the CV procedure will overfit the training set of k folds ?

There is a simulation here:

Figure 2 of:

Gavin C. Cawley, Nicola L. C. Talbot, "On Over-fitting in Model Selection and Subsequent Selection Bias in Performance Evaluation", Journal of Machine Learning Research, 11(70):2079−2107, 2010. [(www)](https://jmlr.org/papers/v11/cawley10a.html)

***My attempt***: We train on k-1 folds and as we increase the complexity of the model we will ***completely*** learn the noise in the k-1 folds, but as we increase the complexity, how do I say that we will completely learn the noise in the k-th fold? Maybe we have the ***same*** kind of sample in the kth fold as learnt by a model in the k-1 folds, but that will happen only for some folds. How can I mix the reasoning in 1 and 2 to create the reason for item 3?

Also, a related query, Section 2.1 of the above paper by Cawley and Talbot says:

The average of the generalisation performance observed over all k folds provides an estimate (with a slightly pessimistic bias) of the generalisation performance of a model trained on the entire sample.

How do I prove the above ?

Edit:

I am trying to understand why we need Nested cross validation and the reason for optimism in flat cross validation. I do see that the hyper parameters are tuned on a certain  set and the accuracy on the ***same*** set is being reported by flat cross validation. I wish to work it out for a small example. Suppose I have decided to fit polynomials to a data set. I have one hyper parameter which is the degree of the polynomial.  We do 6 random splits - train/test of 50% each. We train models from n=1 to n=10. Suppose the true n=5. We may by chance have  data in ALL the ***test*** splits from the model with n=3(too simple a sample)/n=7(too complicated a sample) (unlikely but with non-zero probability). Hence the model chosen by flat cross validation will underfit / overfit(it will learn the ***same*** kind of noise). This ***may*** be discovered by taking an extra sample as nested-cross validation does and measuring the error on that. Query : Is there any difference in optimism due to model selection vs optimism due to hyperparameter tuning ? They seem the ***same*** to me.

Comment: "how do I say that we will completely learn the noise in the k-th fold?" this is an unreasonable expectation.  It only takes partial learning of the noise in the k-th fold for over-fitting in model selection to occur.  This happens via choosing the hyper-parameters, not through choosing the model parameters.

Comment: The kth fold is essentially a "test set", so it will give an unbiased performance estimate for a model trained on (k-1)/k of the available data.  Most models improve with increasing amounts of data, hence this is likely to be a slightly pessimistic estimate of the performance of a model trained on all of the available data (which is generally what you do to get the final model to use in operation).

Comment: "Basically, the validation set may have the same kind of noise as is learned by one of the candidate models." no, this is not correct, the over-fitting happens in choosing the hyper-parameters of the model.  It doesn't have to be "the same kind of noise".

Comment: Dear Sir, ***really*** appreciate all your effort and prompt reply. I am not able to visualize the over fitting due to choosing the hyper-parameters. Let me try though. So suppose the true model is polynomial with n=3. Suppose the model with n=5 degree polynomial overfits this ***whole*** set.  Are we afraid that n=5 fitted on k-1 folds will do well on the kth fold ? Perhaps you have a better idea than me. Please illustrate with an example.

Comment: There is an example already in the paper.  There is no real distinction between parameters and hyper-parameters, it is just a matter of compulational convenience that there is a good optimisation algorithm for one set (which we call parameters) and not for the other (the hyper-parameters) so we tune those using cross-validation.  However, that is just fitting a set of (hyper-) parameters to a finite same of data (the validation set), so the validation error can be reduced in ways that depend on the noise in the validation set, but which doesn't improve generalisation.

Comment: It doesn't depend on whether the model over-fits the training set, it is to do with how many hyper-parameters there are (degrees of freedom) relative to the size of the validation set.