# Overfitting using lightGBM?

Tags: r, overfitting, lightgbm

I have a small dataset composed of 800 data points where I need to perform a regression task. I randomly chose 10% of the dataset to be used as validation.

The problem is that I am not sure if I am overfitting. I can see that RMSE and MAE for the validation dataset is worse than for the training dataset (as expected) but I cannot understand if it is to worse or not.

How can I understand if I am overfitting? How can I solve it?

```
Define the parameters of the model
params = list(
  objective = "regression",
  metric = "l1"
)

#Define LightGBM model
model_lgbm_base = lgb.train(
  params = params,
  nrounds = 50,
  data = train_lgbm
)

#Predict
yhat_fit_base = predict(model_lgbm_base, as.matrix(train_model_x[, 2:12])) #Predict in the train data
yhat_predict_base <- predict(model_lgbm_base, as.matrix(val_x[, 2:12])) #Predict in the validation data

#RMSE
rmse_fit_base = RMSE(as.numeric(unlist(train_model_y)), yhat_fit_base) #2.101565 RMSE train
rmse_predict_base = RMSE(as.numeric(unlist(val_y)), yhat_predict_base) #3.329543 RMSE val

#MAE
mae_fit_base = MAE(as.numeric(unlist(train_model_y)), yhat_fit_base) #1.601823 MAE train 
mae_predict_base = MAE(as.numeric(unlist(val_y)), yhat_predict_base) #2.384942 MAE val
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we are likely overfitting because we get "45%+ more error" moving from the training to the validation set. *That said*, overfitting is properly assessed by using a training, validation *and* a testing set. That is because we can still overfit the validation set, CV.SE has a very enlightening thread on  *[Overfitting the validation set](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/438651/)* if one wants to look at this further.

In addition to the point above and more specific to this post: what we are missing is information about the variability of the performance metric used. For example, if our validation set performance is 80%  and our test performance is 78% but we have a variability of $\pm 6\%$ in our performance metric, then we do not overfit. If we have variability of $\pm 0.6\%$ we do overfit. In order to get some idea of this variability we could use some sort of resampling technique (e.g. $k$-fold cross-validation is the simplest form). That is because simply put overfitting is "learning the noise" and resampling allows us to ameliorate noise's influence.

In terms of references, a very accessible yet thorough discussion can be found in Roberts et al. (2016) *[Cross‐validation strategies for data with temporal, spatial, hierarchical, or phylogenetic structure](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/ecog.02881)*, it deals with ecological data but the learnings are transferable across all domains. More particular to ML, Raschka (2018) *[Model Evaluation, Model Selection, and Algorithm Selection in Machine Learning](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1162/089976698300017197)* is a great short monograph on the comparison of ML algorithms and their variance due to data sampling.